# What is the level of optimization of the java compiler?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

So lets consider this following statement that executes more than a million times inside a loop.

```
boolean validity = condition1 || condition2;
```

It is safe to assume that both ***condition1*** and ***condition2*** have very complex calculation inside them. So since there is an **OR** operator here, I assume it would be wise to separately check for ***condition1*** first and then if necessary, ***condition2*** afterwards like,

```
boolean validity = condition1;
if( !validity )
    validity = condition2;
```

Should I manually perform optimizations like this or does the java compiler automatically takes care of these things?

Comment: should be pretty simple to test that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: OR operation will never check condition2 if condition1 is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Java Language Specification, [§15.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) says:

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|` ([§15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

Thus it's *required* by language specification that the right part is evalutated only if left part is false. It's not an optimization, it's a part of language. Optimizations are not the part of language specification, they may make your code faster, but they should never make your code to behave differently. Here however the behavior would be different if both parts were evaluated as the right part might have a side-effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tagir. So are there any cases where an eager operation is preferred over a short circuit one?

Comment: @KiranR, actually I don't know such cases. FindBugs tries to [report](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NS_NON_SHORT_CIRCUIT) when non-short-circuit boolean expressions are detected and I don't remember that anybody complained that such report is false-positive (I'm a FindBugs contributor). Probably it was added in Java 1.0 just to be closer to C... Of course `|` for int/long type is very useful, but not for boolean.

Answer (score -1):

The java compiler is capable to execute the function for condition1 at first. When it is true then the function for condition2 is not executed any longer. So the optimization is not required. This is as there is an OR-Operation.

Comment: apparently you didn't read the answer. compared to the other I wrote exactly the same. But without the reference to the spec.